# Update Flatlist, Pull to Refresh, Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

Thanks for any help...

I am trying to add a flatlist with pull to refresh ability.

My actions that post to Firebase work and my flatlist showing userPosts works on a separate profile screen (via auto-update of redux state change instead of pull to refresh).

The console logs "allPosts before" and "allPosts after" show that the array of firebase responses IS being updated.  As the code is now, when refresh is pulled, a blank post pops up as if it knows its been updated but the values or formats are misaligned.

Any help would be highly appreciated.  Thanks again. -Matt

`` Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See /fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.%s, Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`. ``

Actions:

```
//get first five posts
export const getPosts = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const posts = await Fire.shared.db.collection('posts').orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(5).get() //get all the posts'

            let array = []
            posts.forEach((post) => {
                array.push(post.data())
            })

            dispatch({ type: 'GET_POSTS', payload: array })
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
}

//get additional posts
export const addPostsBefore = (getState) => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        try {
            console.log("array.allPosts before addPostsBefore: " + JSON.stringify(getState().feed.allPosts.length) )
            const posts = await Fire.shared.db.collection('posts').where('timestamp', '>=', getState().feed.allPosts[0].timestamp).orderBy("timestamp", "asc").limitToLast(10).get() 
            if (posts) {
                console.log("Firebase response to be added: " + posts )
                let array = []
                posts.forEach((post) => {
                    array.push(post.data())
                })
                console.log("array.length: " + array.length )
                dispatch({ type: 'TO_BE_ADDED', payload: array })
                console.log("array.allPosts after addPostsBefore: " + JSON.stringify(getState().feed.allPosts.length) )
            } else {
                return null
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
let feedDefaultState = {}
const feed = (state = feedDefaultState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
        case 'TO_BE_ADDED':
            return {...state, allPosts: [action.payload, ...state.allPosts]}
        case 'GET_POSTS':
            return { ...state, allPosts: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Screen/Flatlist:

````
<FlatList
    data={this.props.feed.allPosts}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}                        
    refreshing={false}                        
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}                        
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
    <View><Text>{item.postDescription}</Text></View>
    }                           
/>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `key` attribute on JSX returned by `renderItem`. This is required as an optimization by react

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.feed.allPosts}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}                        
    refreshing={false}                        
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}                        
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
    <View key={item.id}><Text>{item.postDescription}</Text></View>
    }                           
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work.  I think it is something with my Firebase response.  Is it possible that instead of adding to the existing allPosts redux state I am creating a new one?  For instance, I want to take the existing allPosts store/array and insert in a new post ```[{new post}, {old posts}]``` but instead I think something like this is happening ```[{new post}], [{old posts}]``` ? I am not sure...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by dispatching and amending each post.data() response from Firebase separately instead of first creating an array of posts to be added and attempting to amend that.

I am guessing there is a more efficient way to do this in one step instead of several dispatches but I dont know it.

```
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        try {
            const posts = await Fire.shared.db.collection('posts').where('timestamp', '>', getState().feed.allPosts[0].timestamp).orderBy("timestamp", "asc").limitToLast(10).get() 
            posts.forEach((post) => {
                 dispatch({ type: 'TO_BE_ADDED', payload: post.data()})
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
```